# How to trigger dialog with JS before leaving current page

Tags: javascript

When a user have changed something in a form, then clicks on any link that will direct him to another page, I'd like to trigger a popup with a "Would you like to Save before leaving?" option.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var shouldConfirm = false;
     window.onbeforeunload = function() {
         if(shouldConfirm) {
             return "You have made unsaved changes. Would you still like to leave this page?";
         }
     }
 </script>

 <input id="FullName" type="text" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('FullName').onchange = function() {
         shouldConfirm = true;
     }
 </script>
```

There's a full article at [4GuysFromRolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134123/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100604-1.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done but this is not always reliable:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function leaving()
 {
    if(confirm("Would you like to save?"))
     {
        //Save info
     }
    else
     {
        //Don't save
     }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onUnload="leaving()">
<!--Stuff-->
</body>
</html>
```